# Bind data in TextBox behind the vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is method which I use now to bind data in TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="txtFormat" ID="txtKOV" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("KOV")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

Now I have to create dynamically form and to bind data behind the vb code. I created the TextBox control like this:

```
For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(1).Rows

    Dim txtKOV As New TextBox()
    txtKOV.ID = "txtKOV_" + Row(columnName:="ID")
    txtKOV.CssClass = "txtFormat"
    holder.Controls.Add(txtKOV)

Next
```

And now I want to do something like this:

```
    txtKOV.Text = '<%# Bind(" + Row(columnName:="NAME") + ")%>'
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Since You create dynamically `TextBox` for each row/record, just put value, eg `txtKov.Text = Row(columnName:="NAME")`... I don't see purpose for that what You want... maybe to provide more info.

Comment: I want to select a row from a GriedView and to fill the form with the data from it and to do update on that row.

Comment: nelek, I have done like you suggested and it works. Post an answer.